# Is there a captcha replacement service like this

Tags: ajax, captcha

You sign up once with a website - say: ireallyamahuman.com and enter a load of captcha stuff so you can be really sure it is a human.

A website uses a simple api - similar to facebook/google login to check with irallyamahuman.com

So the captcha can just be a big button that says 'I really am a human' (so long as you are already logged in to the ireallyamahuman site) - hopefully this can all happen automatically without even having/pressing the button.

What are the cross domain problems/solutions with this idea?

Comment: What would prevent somebody to sign up with ireallyamhuman.com and write a bot to use this account to pretend he's human?

Comment: I would expect that ireallyamahuman.com would have a method to revoke human credentials based on crowd sourcing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will reduce the net work required to "go among the living" (crawl the web pretending to be a human).  It means you only have to put *one* job out on [Mechanical Turk](http://elie.im/publication/how-good-are-humans-at-solving-captchas-a-large-scale-evaluation) (log in to ireallyamahuman.com then send me the cookie), rather than one per site (or even one per form submission for some sites)

Basically, sites have no incentive to reduce CAPTCHA work, quite the opposite.

Comment: as above: I would expect that ireallyamahuman.com would have a method to revoke human credentials based on crowd sourcing.

Comment: @Billy, sure, you can delete accounts.  But they're still probably going to get more spam done per crowdsource job than they would without IRAAH.

Comment: What about some kind of sponsorship system where you can only get an account via an existing account holder, and any bad behavior bubbles up the chain reflecting badly on sponsors, and repeated behavior leads to account blocked. That would make it difficult to set up a system to obtain accounts.